# Div fill vertical space of wrapper and margins

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two `div`, one at left with 49% `width`, then 2% `margin` and then another `div` at 49% `width` as well. But I have a problem with the vertical space, as well as with the `margin`.

---

**DEMO**

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: tomato;
 }
        
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right: 2%;
        background-color: pink;
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of that code: https://jsfiddle.net/L6k5ocyr/3/

I think I am missing something, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        vertical-align: top;
}
```

Try this.

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: tomato;
 }
        
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right: 2%;
        background-color: pink;
        vertical-align: top;  /* edited */
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll stick with this solution, the most simple thing ever :)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: tomato;
 }
        
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right: 2%;
        background-color: pink;
        float:left;  /* edited */
        
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 49%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

try this :

```
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
     float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `float` property see snippet

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: tomato;
 }
        
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 49%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) when wanting to do stuff like this.
I edited your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6k5ocyr/4/) to show what flexbox can do.

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: tomato;
 }
 
 .Footer-firstElement > * {
       flex: 0;
       min-width: 49%;
 }
        
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: pink;
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in another comment here, flexbox is something to avoid.The compatibility is really poor, and the side effects uncontrollable.

Comment: Please do some research before commenting, flexbox is supported by [more than 95% of all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), the only browser that flexbox is largely broken in is IE11.

Comment: Then you should know that Firefox has problems with Flexbox as well, apart of IE11 as you said. So there we have two of the most used browsers without full support for your website, great.

Comment: True, but seeing that those bugs would not affect the layout that was desired, I  would say that is is safe to use flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Not change much, just adding display `flex` to the parents and `flex:1;` to the children.

```css
.Footer-firstElement {
        height: 200px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        background-color: tomato;
        display: flex;
 }
   
.Footer-firstElementLeft {
        flex:1;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: pink;
        margin-right: 8;
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
        flex:1;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: gold;
        margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Footer-firstElement">
  <div class="Footer-firstElementLeft">
    <a href="#">Foo bar </a>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer-firstElementRight">
    Foo bar <br />
    Foo bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is terrible, and much more complicated than people thinks. In fact, I am doing this because my site was entirely structured by flexbox, and you can't imagine the amount of problems it had depending of the browser. So I'll stick with other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this case

```
.Footer-firstElement {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
 }

.Footer-firstElementLeft {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right: 2%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.Footer-firstElementRight {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: gold;
}
```